# Downgrading ReaderWriterLockSlim UpgradeableReadLock to simple ReadLock

Tags: c#, locking

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock.aspx) of `ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterUpgradeableReadLock` says:

> A thread in upgradeable mode can downgrade to read mode or upgrade to write mode.

How do I downgrade the lock to a read lock? The documentation does't tell...

[Edit:] I'm not trying to get the write lock. I just want to downgrade the upgradeable lock to a read lock so that another thread can acquire the upgradeable lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation for [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) (the class itself):

"A thread in upgradeable mode can downgrade to read mode by first calling the EnterReadLock method and then calling the ExitUpgradeableReadLock method."

Comment: My mistake for not reading the documentation till the end. Thanks!